# custom validation rule for integer range in jquery validation engine

Tags: jquery, regex, jquery-validation-engine

I am using [JQuery Validation Engine](https://github.com/posabsolute/jQuery-Validation-Engine) library. I am trying to create a custom validation either through `Regex` or `custom method` to validate the field input.

I would suggest this validation name as `custom integer validation containing integer range or some integers separated by comma(s) or combination of both`.

Here is the criteria:

1. can enter any integer. For e.g. `89`
2. can enter any integer range. For e.g. `12-18` or `15-18` but not `19-3 (range should between min to max)`
3. can enter any combination of above two inputs separated by comma(,) only with or without spaces between comma. For e.g. `1-6, 5, 8-13, 7`. **But not** `-3-5 (not -3)` or `3-7-, 10 (not 7-)`

I tried this custom rule:

```
"integerRangeComma": {                    
             "regex": /^(([0-9]+)([\,]([0-9]+))?|([\,]([0-9]+))?)$/,
             "alertText": "* Invalid floating decimal number"
          },
```

My intended purpose to do the above validation is:

I have a list of total documents lets suppose `12`. I created a text-box in the form to accept what document no, he likes to add in his profile. And the above criteria should be applied on that.

My next question would be, I also must validate that numbers entered by user do not greater than `12 (my presumption)`.

How can I achieve this either through creating my own custom rule or something else.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Show us how your custom validation script is going

Comment: Let me be more clear, [what have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: You should update your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing maths with regex is always a pain, you should parse it and check the *not greater than 12* condition with code. However, it is possible for this simple example by using

```
[0-9]|1[12]
```

Your combination for an input of a single integer or a range will then be

```
number(-number)?
```

and for one input, or two commaseparated ones is

```
input(\s*,\s*input)?
```

If you want more than two, use `*` for unlimited or `{0,n}` for limited repetion instead of the `?`.

So together, you get

```
var integerRangeComma = {                    
     "regex": /^([0-9]|1[12])(-[0-9]|-1[12])?(\s*,\s*([0-9]|1[12])(-[0-9]|-1[12])?)?$/,
     "alertText": "a single page number until 12 or an interval in them, or two of those separated by a comma"
};
```

Comment: It seems to be working. I also want to make it as required field, then where should I have to change.

Comment: Doesn't that regex refuse empty strings? I don't know your plugin, check its documentation on how to make an input required.